# Log viewer server and client

Tags: windows, linux, logging, viewer

I'm looking for a log viewing solution for (mostly) Linux and (preferably) Windows too. I want to be able to centralize the log information for a lot of servers so that people in the company can see what's going on for different servers.

I would guess this would involve having a central server which accepts information from the various computers / virtual machines with (perhaps) a running daemon on each of the servers.

Does such a software exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if [syslog-ng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog-ng) can be of any help :)

There are many others but IMO this is the most popular one.

Cheers!

Comment: You will need to install Cygwin environment for Windows, but I agree - syslog-ng is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ReflectInsight](http://insightextensions.codeplex.com). Look at the Router Service. It handles exactly what you are asking for.

DISCLAIMER: I'm one of the developers for ReflectInsight.

[image]